# IoT can't connect to the server with MQTT+TLS

Tags: ssl, mqtt, iot

I use MQTT+tls to connect the IoT device to the server with GPRS supported by SIM900.

The IoT device connects to the server without any problem on HTTP or HTTPs.

However, When I set up the ssl proxy on the server with Tomcat,the IoT device can get status of "send ok" successfully,but always gets "wait send ok ack timeout" error.

The wireshark installed on the server can't capture any useful infomation.

Comment: You cannot use a HTTPS proxy with raw MQT. Are you using MQTT over websockets?

Comment: "wireshark installed on the server can't capture any useful infomation" -- I think the clue has to come from transport layer. The things to look for is 
1. Can your MQTT client side ignore server certificate validation issues
2. Are doing two way SSL? In that case is the server identifying you client correctly?
3. some time cipher mismatch leads to handshaking errors. 

In all these cases you can rely on the TCP dump

Comment: The server requests client certificate with a CertificateRequest. Can I disable this request so the server doesn't require a client certificate?

Comment: The MQTT client will manage to do a SSL handshake with tomcat but get no further as you can not proxy MQTT via a HTTP proxy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

on SIM900 you can't use TCP+SSL. That's why you can do it with HTTPS but you can't do it with MQTT+SSL. You could use the MQTT protocol without SSL.

What I did to get this working (MQTT+SSL) on SIM900 was encrypting the data using wolfSSL and then send it through a TCP, without SSL, connection.