# How to connect GPRS+GPS smartwatch to Google Cloud IoT by setting IP and address?

Tags: gps, gprs, google-cloud-iot

I want to connect smartwatches with GPS and GPRS communication supporting TCP protocol to Google Cloud. I have an API with the communication protocol, including configuration of IP port and server address where the data is sent, as well as all the information to decode the sent data, but I do not have access to the source code.

Knowing that, is it possible to connect these devices to a registry in Google Cloud core-iot with MQTT protocol? Or do I have to set a server using a VM and receive the data there?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

If your "smartwatch device" (device) can connect to the Internet, you could configure the MQTT client to connect directly from it. IIRC, it could be complicated to do this over a GPRS connection, particularly if you're having to do [MQTT+TLS over GPRS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38713176/iot-cant-connect-to-the-server-with-mqtttls).

If you don't have internet connectivity from your device, you still have other options. For example, if you have Bluetooth on the device, you could create a companion application for a phone that could work as a [gateway](https://cloud.google.com/iot/docs/how-tos/gateways/) between the device and Google over Bluetooth.

Regardless of the approach you take, you would need to implement the following:

- Generate a JWT token for connecting to the device bridge
- Connect using an MQTT client

The actual implementation details will depend on the hardware capabilities of your device. For example, there are examples in Android using the [Cloud IoT Core client for Android Things](https://cloud.google.com/iot/docs/reference/android-things/javadoc/) that should be relatively straightforward to port to Android.